# Linking to a different site with href tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use the a tag below to go to www.facebook.com/group:

```
<a href="www.facebook.com/group" target="_blank"></a>
```

Instead of that link I want, the link takes me to http://www.goups.com/www.facebook.com/group . How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Add `http://` in front

Comment: put http:// in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

A link without `http://` at the start is used only for pages in your website.

If you want external link, you need to put `http://` at the start.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/group" target="_blank"></a>
```